# Conditionally including a template file in ui:composition tag

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am using facelets for templating in my jsf application. I would like to including a template file conditionally in ui:composition tag. If user is logged in the template must be "authorized.xhtml" and if the user is not logged in then the template must be "unauthorized.xhtml". Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/unauthorized.xhtml">
<ui:composition template="/templates/authorized.xhtml">
```

I am using JSF 1.2.

Comment: I am now retrieving the template value from a method in backing bean where I am checking whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in I return "/templates/authorized.xhtml" else I return "/templates/unauthorized.xhtml'. I am unable to post this as an answer right not as I don't have 100 reputation points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try ternary operation on `isAuthorized()` attribute, if you have one in your log-in bean:

```
<ui:composition template="#{loginbean.authorized ? '/templates/authorized.xhtml' : '/templates/unauthorized.xhtml'}">
```

Or use two `<h:panelGroup>` tags with appropriate `rendered` values:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{loginbean.authorized}">
    <ui:decorate template="/templates/authorized.xhtml">
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not loginbean.authorized}">
    <ui:decorate template="/templates/unauthorized.xhtml">
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: The panelgroup approach won't work. The `<ui:composition>` is supposed to be the root tag. The EL approach will however work fine.

Comment: You're right. One have to use `<ui:decorate>` instead of `<ui:composition>`